# Can i use two or more Microsoft Speech Recognition engines?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-platform

Can i use two or more Microsoft Speech Recognition engines at the same machine (with same language)?

I have task on speech recognition and i try to recognize too big grammar (2000+ words).

So, i think to divide this big grammar on two grammars. One grammar load to first engine and other-at second.

But i do not know- is this SpeechRecognitinEngine instances referenced to 2 difference speech engines or it just linked to one engine?

Here is my code:

```
List<String> words1 = new List<string>();
words1.Add("one");

List<String> words2 = new List<string>();
words2.Add("two");

var gr1 = MakeGrammar("gr1", words1);
var gr2 = MakeGrammar("gr2", words2);

var gr3 = MakeGrammar("gr1", words1); // create new grammar with name gr1- to check on grammar unic name exception.

MicSpeechRecEngine1.LoadGrammar(gr1);  (where MicSpeechRecEngine is SpeechRecognitionEngine)

MicSpeechRecEngine2.LoadGrammar(gr2);
MicSpeechRecEngine2.LoadGrammar(gr3);

public static Grammar MakeGrammar(String name,List<String> words)
{
    Choices choises = new Choices();
    GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
    gb.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");


    if (choises == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("choises is null!");
    if (words == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("Words is null!");
    choises.Add(words.ToArray());

    if (gb != null)
    {
        //gb.Append(choises); 
        gb.Append(choises, 0, 10);
    }

    Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
    g.Name = name;
    g.Priority = 0;
    g.Weight = 1.0f;
    g.Enabled = true;

    return g;
}
```

This code works well- when i say -"one" - it types "one one"-from both engines.

My point is to make 2 or more engines, load two or more big grammar and if it is recognize on difference engines- get performance (and validate) recognition.

Thank you!

P.S. Thank you for responce!

Ok, i rewrite some piece of code:

```
var gr3 = MakeGrammar("gr3", words3);
```

So, at that line i create a new grammar.
And i can load it to second engine.

So, gr1 will load to Engine1, gr2,g3- to Engine2.

I know,it is stupid question, but:
Can be that Engine1 and Engine2 is just references to some Engine that recognize this grammars (grammars are big)?
I hope that is not,because i want to create 1 to N engines at my machine, load 1 to N grammar (one big grammar to one engine) and try to recognize it.
Thank you!

Comment: Seems to me that you just aren't allowed to reuse the grammar objects. Try creating separate objects.

Comment: xm.. i do it like you say... use the same object to two engines...

Comment: @Chris , but how can i understand - i use the same engine,or two difference?

Comment: You're still passing `gr1` to both engines. Try creating completely separate grammar objects.

Comment: What's the exception? Also try giving them unique names, in case something is shared internally in the api.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies in the following:

```
MicSpeechRecEngine1.LoadGrammar(gr1);  (where MicSpeechRecEngine is SpeechRecognitionEngine)

MicSpeechRecEngine2.LoadGrammar(gr2);
MicSpeechRecEngine2.LoadGrammar(gr3);
```

As Chris stated in the comment section you're loading the same grammar twice.
In the part where you create grammar you're giving your grammars the same name as seen here:

```
var gr1 = MakeGrammar("gr1", words1);
var gr2 = MakeGrammar("gr2", words2);

var gr3 = MakeGrammar("gr1", words1);
```

Both gr3 and gr1 are the same to SAPI. So when you load them, you're loading "one" to both. Which is why you're getting "one one".

When you call LoadGrammar() I believe you're clearing the previous grammar. So the code:

```
MicSpeechRecEngine2.LoadGrammar(gr2);
MicSpeechRecEngine2.LoadGrammar(gr3);
```

Actually becomes:

```
MicSpeechRecEngine2.LoadGrammar(gr3);
```

As far as SAPI is concerned anyway.

From what I see, it does seem like you do infact have two recognizers running however.

Answer (score -1):

You can certainly run two speech engines in one page of code. In fact, you could run numerous one's with different strings. I am inserting some snap-shots of mine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uglSO.png)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68591593/edit) this answer instead of posting a string of answers. The site is not a forum and does not work with threads.